# Creating strange form with only CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, shapes

I've encounter a doubts of how to approach a project which im busy at this time. I need to create a header with a strange form. This project needs to be responsive in any modern device. I've checked different blogs searching for help such as shapes of CSS. This has helped me but I do not know which would be the best approach for this.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

The design which is wished is something similar as this image:

[image]

As you can see there are two curves on each side which are also different from each other. I would like this to be a header element. Is it possible to create with only one element? Any suggestions of how to reach this kind of irregular forms with CSS?

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this by using [`border-top-left-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius) and [`border-top-right-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-right-radius), and setting them at different values.

[**Example jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JYTcL/)

---

If you'd like to set the border radius individually for all four corners, use the more general [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) property. It's syntax is:

```
border-radius: top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left
```

[**Example jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JYTcL/1/)

---

`border-radius` is supported in all major browsers, except older versions of IE (IE8 and before).

If you'd like `border-radius` to work in older versions of IE (6, 7, 8), you could look into using [**CSS3 PIE**](http://css3pie.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a codepen of the desired header in the question.

Depending on your header size you will need to play with the numbers; but this should kick you off in the right direction.

http://codepen.io/BuoyantMedia/pen/ubIpG

Comment: Hi, this works but I'm checking that it seems that your using a div in the body (rectangle-inner) to form the header as it should. But my question was more focused into only using one tag and make that shape. I will use <header> and I want that tag to get this form. Is this possible? I will use more times this shape so I need to learn how to apply this to one element without using different divs. you get it?

Comment: Codepen is back up. I would appreciate you remarking my answer as correct if it is still most correct with this code example. Thank you.

Comment: I gave already a point +, but it's still not the answer. I was asking if it's possible to do this shape only with the <header> tag. Not using the div or wrapper where the content is placed. But your answer gets very close and therefore I gave a point.